# Getting error in react while installing color detect library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, image-processing, dependencies

I have this Spotify-clone project. I'm trying to detect the image's dominant color and use that color as background color.

Currently, I have tried using color-theif, node-vibrant, extract- colors libraries. But I'm getting below errors while adding any one of these libraries into my project.

How can I fix this?

Error -

```
PS D:\React\spotify-clone> **npm install color-thief**
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-axios@2.0.6
npm ERR! Found: axios@1.6.7
npm ERR! node_modules/axios
npm ERR!   axios@"^1.6.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer axios@"^0.27.2" from react-axios@2.0.6
npm ERR! node_modules/react-axios
npm ERR!   react-axios@"^2.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: axios@0.27.2
npm ERR! node_modules/axios
npm ERR!   peer axios@"^0.27.2" from react-axios@2.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-axios
npm ERR!     react-axios@"^2.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-17T13_30_34_980Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-17T13_30_34_980Z-debug-0.log



PS D:\React\spotify-clone> **npm install --save extract-colors**
npm ERR!   react-axios@"^2.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: axios@0.27.2
npm ERR! node_modules/axios
npm ERR!   peer axios@"^0.27.2" from react-axios@2.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-axios
npm ERR!     react-axios@"^2.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-17T13_46_00_204Z-eresolve-report.txt
```

Below is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "spotify-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-axios": "^2.0.6",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.20.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "swiper": "^11.0.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "both": "concurrently \"npm run start\" \"nodemon backend/index.js\""
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object": "^7.23.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the color detect library package;

the issue lies with `react-axios`, that requires an outdated version of `axios`.

In your case, simply run `npm uninstall axios`, and then afterward, run `npm i` to reinstall the necessary dependencies.

Comment: Im using axios to fetch data from API. It will affect my code right??

Comment: There should be no issue if you remove the installation of `axios`. The next time you run `npm i`, `react-axios` will install [`axios`](https://github.com/sheaivey/react-axios/blob/master/package.json#L50) in version `^0.27.2` for you